# global namespace and this in coffeescript loops

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

in this code:

```
class MyClass
  myfun: (arg) ->
    for x in arg
      do ->
        ...
```

the scope outside of the loop is MyClass, while inside of the loop (it's an anonymous function) the scope changes to the DOMWindow.

Why does this happen? How can I prevent it? My main problem is that I can't access other functions inside the MyClass class if the scope changes.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**fat arrow**](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow) syntax to bind the a function to the current context:

```
class MyClass
  myfun: (arg) ->
    for x in arg
      do =>
        ...
```

This happens because the `do` keyword just calls the function without any context, so it defaults to  the `window` object.

```
do -> ...
```

Is equivalent to

```
(function() {
    ...
}());
```

Comment: Good answer. For more info on how `this`/`@` works in JavaScript/CoffeeScript, see [JavaScript Garden](http://javascriptgarden.info/#function.this), or (plug) [my CoffeeScript book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript).